# Clickable views inside scrollview

Tags: scrollview, view, clickable

I have a few views inside scrollview. When I set clickable true for them, the scrollview does not scroll, when I set  clickable false for them, scrollview can be scrollable. How to make the scrollview scrollable even when the views have clickable set to true? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use them inside nestedscrollview. It will handle them all.